# Rails form for mailing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms, form-for

I'm trying to build a form which preloads content from two models (two variables being passed, being shown in the textfields) and then, **not saves** the data **but sends** the altered content (from the textfields) as two(?) variables to a mailer class.

I've managed to preload the data from one of the two models but am not sure how the form_for tag has to look like to get both models loaded as well as targeting the mailer class method instead of updating the model entity when pressing "send".

Do I need the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` attribute inside the model if I'm not saving anything?

I hope someone could give me an small example of the crucial parts. A thousand thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fields_for` to include other models in same form. You can use it inside the same form_for what is present.

Checkout the example here from the api docs,

```
  <%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
      First name: <%= person_form.text_field :first_name %>
      Last name : <%= person_form.text_field :last_name %>

      <%= fields_for @person.permission do |permission_fields| %>
        Admin?  : <%= permission_fields.check_box :admin %>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

when you submit the data from this form, you can just use that data to pass to the mailer class from controller. `UserMailer.get_user_info(params[:name], params[:address]).send`

```
 Creates a scope around a specific model object like #form_for, but doesn't create the form tags themselves. This makes #fields_for suitable for specifying additional model objects in the same form.
```

Refer Docs here:.
[fields_for(record_name, record_object = nil, options = {}, &block)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this solution work as well for two models which only have a "through" connection? Or no connection at all?

Comment: It will not work for no connection. It works for nested model attributes